# MVC custom route not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I defined my route like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductAPI",
    url: "{productId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
    constraints: new { productId= @"\d{15}" }
);
```

And the link is made with

```
@Html.ActionLink("PRD List", "GetPrdList", "PrdList", new { productId = @ViewBag.productId}, null)
```

The above link leads to The resource cannot be found. I am new to routing concepts, please help me with my mistake from the above code.

I would want my URL to look like ../ProductID/{controller}/{action}/{id}, if productID is not specified in the URL, it should pick up the default URL ../{controller}/{action}/{id}

Comment: Do you have a controller named `PrdListController` with `public ActionResult GetPrdList(int productId)`?

Comment: Then your link should be creating `.../PrdList/GetPrdList?productId=someValue` and your method will be hit. Can you confirm that is the actual url generated.

Comment: Yes link creates like .../PrdList/GetPrdList?productId=someValue, Is there anyway, I can have my link like .../somevalue/PrdList/GetPrdList

Comment: add [Route(name)] on top of method

Comment: Adding Route name didn't help too. Output - The resource cannot be found

Comment: Then it will work fine. And yes, you could generate a route like `../somevalue/PrdList/GetPrdList` but you need a specific route and it needs to come before the default. If you edit you question to explain what you really wanting to do, I will add an answer

Comment: Thank you Stephen, essentially, I would want my URL to look like ../ProductID/{controller}/{action}/{id}, if productID is not specified in the URL, it should pick up the default URL ../{controller}/{action}/{id}

Comment: @AKarthik, I don't answer comments, only questions so you need to edit your question :)

Comment: Done, question edited

Comment: @AKarthik, Need a break, but will add an answer in an hour or so :)

Comment: @AKarthik, Have just studied your edit. You can create specific routes - e.g. `url: "{productId}/PrdList/GetPrdList/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "PrdList", action = "GetPrdList", id = UrlParameter.Optional },` and place them before the Default route, but if your want this for every action in every controller, then you need a specific route for all of them. Not really sure what your trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Thanks Stephen, basically moving my custom route above default route made it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this code in your WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Other",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```